# PostgreSQL 9.3 failing on createuser in Travis

Tags: postgresql, travis-ci

This behavior from Travis CI is new:

`$ sudo -u postgres createuser -p 5432 travis &>/dev/null
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n)`

The build dies before going any further, because it’s waiting for user input that it will never get. My Travis config [looks like this](https://github.com/openaddresses/machine/blob/9e299ed66ec184060e17184dfef296c492d37eeb/.travis.yml#L8), with the 9.3 addon specified. [Build 72615655](https://travis-ci.org/openaddresses/machine/jobs/72615655) is a sample failure, while build 72408935 is a successful build from two days ago with an identical Travis configuration.

Comment: Closing stdin might be useful; append `</dev/null`. Though it shouldn't be necessary, really.

Comment: I have the very same problem. I think they changed something in their configuration recently

Comment: What happens if you add the option `--no-superuser`

Comment: This looks to be a bug internal to Travis, so I can’t add any option or change the call to `createuser`. Travis’s “Help” sent me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Travis reports that this has been fixed: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4584

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue in Travis CI for PostgreSQL.
By adding `sudo: false` solved the issue.

my .travis.yml

```
addons:
  postgresql: "9.4"

sudo: false
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I currently rely on sudo in my tests, so I am continuing to use the Travis legacy infrastructure.